# How do I force a VB.NET script to run before the page itself in ASP.NET WebForms?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have a script which is included in my page:

```
<script runat="server" language="VB" src="../AdditionalField/AdditionalFieldSave.aspx"></script>
```

edit: wrong script, I meant this one:

```
<!-- #include file="../AdditionalField/AdditionalFieldDisplayHTML.aspx" -->
```

yes, you can `#include` in WebForms, apparently!

Inside this script I am adding some values to a list:

```
If myAdditionalFieldTempReader("Mandatory") Then
    MandatoryAdditionalFields.Add("Notes" & additionalFieldFoundCount)
End If
```

And then back in the page I am retrieving the values from the list:

```
jQuery("#YouthEdit").validate({
    rules: {
        BirthDate: {
            required: true,
            date: true
        },
        FirstName: {
            required: true,
        },
        LastName: {
            required: true,
        }
        <%
        For Each mf As String In MandatoryAdditionalFields
            Response.Write("," & mf & ": {required: true}")
        Next
        %>
    },
    messages: {
        BirthDate: "Enter a birth date",
        FirstName: "Enter a First Name",
        LastName: "Enter a Last Name"
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) { 
        //form.submit();
        document.YouthEdit.submit();
    }
    });
```

My problem is that when I retrieve the values from the list, the list is still empty; it hasn't been populated yet. How can I force the script to run before the page itself so the values are present when I need them?

edit: OK, I tried this:

`<input id="mandatoryAdditionalFieldsHidden" type="hidden" value="" runat="server" />`

on the include page and this:

`mandatoryAdditionalFieldsHidden.Value = String.Join(",", MandatoryAdditionalFields)`

in a function called from `Page_Init` on the main page and

```
var mandatoryAdditionalFields = jQuery("#mandatoryAdditionalFieldsHidden").val().split(',');
for (field in mandatoryAdditionalFields)
    rules.push([field, 'required: true']);
```

in the main page JavaScript. And now I get an error saying I can't call `split` on `undefined`... why would the hidden field have an undefined value when I set it in the Page_Init?

Comment: I suggest that you put the information in an `<input ID="somethingSensible" type="hidden" value="your data">` element. Do that in the Page_Load handler. Extract that data with some more jQuery. Using `Response.Write` in webforms usually indicates that you're doing something against the way it's meant to be done.

Comment: Tried that, it didn't seem to work. Updated my post with the code I used.

Comment: If you look at the source of the page in the browser, does the hidden input get the correct value?

Comment: No, it does not. If I set some breakpoints I can see that Page_Init is running before the script is setting the list of mandatory fields. Let me try Page_Load as you originally suggested...

Comment: Nope, Page_Load didn't work, nor did Page_PreRender. No matter what event I handle, the code runs before the included script sets the list of mandatory fields...

Comment: Hang on... have you removed the `<script runat="server" language="VB" src="../AdditionalField/AdditionalFieldSave.aspx"></script>` yet? That should not be in there.

Comment: No, I have not. That's how we're including the script to save the fields. I think it's a holdover from when this was a classic ASP page, if I'm not mistaken. If I remove it, I'll need to find another way to include the script... maybe make it a user control?

Comment: Oh, hang on, I was talking about the wrong script - edited my post!

Comment: Yes, a user control should be more reliable, or at least more in line with how webforms are meant to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your jquery code in this way, so it's executed only once the page has been loaded:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Put your code here.
});
```

Comment: Oh, it was already wrapped in `jQuery().ready(function() {}`, let me try `jQuery(document).ready(function() {}`... nope, that didn't help!